# How should my query look like?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I use SQL Server 2008 and dispose a table, that I group data on one column. For some reasons I have to use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT` (it's a part of more complex query). Query results (only one column is returned) are fine for me.

The problem is, that I want to use this query, as a subquery in `WHERE` clause to filter data based on this subquery. As I see, `WHERE` clause sees in this subquery not only data that is displayed in query results after grouping by, but also the rest of them and this is what I do not like.

My question is, how can I use my `group by` query as a subquery in where clause that would see only results after grouping by?

Comment: It is always good practice to post your SQL code in your question.  In this case, what you need is a subquery (parentheses around the group by query, then use the result in another query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to select the required column from your existing subquery. And then pass this new subquery as input to `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your issue is that your main query is returning multiple rows for each of the items in your `WHERE` sub-query. This is the correct behaviour. In order to limit the results in your main query you must use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` in the main query.